# i am trying to increase my number by 1 every time my code runs

Tags: python, function, selenium

the problem i'm having is that every time i go to a new function and then go back to the first one, the count starts over.`yo(driver) random(driver) yo(driver)`. the second time i do yo(driver) the count starts over and if i place `count = 0` outside of the function then it comes up as an unresolved reference inside of the function. is there any simple way i can get it keep counting and not start over?

```
timeout = time.time()+2

def yo(driver):
    count = 0
    while True:
        try:
            print("try 1")
            count += 1
        except:
            print("except 1")
        else:
            print("else 1")
        finally:
            print("finally 1")
            if time.time() > timeout:
                print("timeout")
                print("count", count)
                break

def random(driver):
    print("yoyo")

yo(driver)
random(driver)
yo(driver)
```

Comment: In addition to JRose's answer below, you could also pass a count into the function that is defined outside of the function, or just reference a count already defined in the outer scope. If you want a topic to look into that could help your understanding of this problem I would look into "Python scope of variables"

Comment: these answers are great! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you can declare a method specific variable and have its state be updated each time you change it during method invocation.

```
def yo():
    yo.count += 1
    print(yo.count)

yo.count = 0

yo()
yo()
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

timeout = time.time()+2

def yo():
    while True:
        try:
            print("try 1")
            yo.count += 1
        except:
            print("except 1")
        else:
            print("else 1")
        finally:
            print("finally 1")
            if time.time() > timeout:
                print("timeout")
                print("count", yo.count)
                break
yo.count = 0
yo()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define `count` as a global variable, and define it a global inside your function:

```
count = 0

def yo(driver):
     global count
     while True:
          try:
               print("try 1")
               count += 1
          except:
               print("except 1")
          else:
               print("else 1")
          finally:
               print("finally 1")
               if time.time() > timeout:
                    print("timeout")
                    print("count", count)
                    break
```

Or you can pass it as a function argument:

```
def yo(driver, count):
     while True:
          try:
               print("try 1")
               count += 1
          except:
               print("except 1")
          else:
               print("else 1")
          finally:
               print("finally 1")
               if time.time() > timeout:
                    print("timeout")
                    print("count", count)
                    break
    return count
count = 0
count = yo(driver, count)
random(driver)
count = yo(driver, count)
```